# Simulating shell like behavior

Tags: c

So what I want is when the user presses the up button, I want to instantly display the command and not show the  ^[[A I already know how to identify up and down from the keyboard, and I know termios might be the solution, but coming from a java background, I don't quite know how to do this. Ncurses is not an option, due to certain constraints. If you can, please help.

What I expect to happen is, when the user presses the up button, I want to instantly do a printf on the same line

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{

    char input[100];
    char *history[5];
    int currentHistory=0;
    int historyCount=5;
    history[0]="hi";
    history[1]="bye";
    history[2]="computer";
    history[3]="science";
    history[4]="Yo";


    while(input[0]!='Q')
    {
       if(input[0]==LEFT_ARROW;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll find this functionality, and more, in either the GNU [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) or the BSD [editline](http://www.thrysoee.dk/editline/) libraries.  They offer largely the same functionality, however the GNU readline library is under a GPL license, and editline is under a BSD license.

Comment: This is a common class assignment, I know I did it for class years ago.  Often using extra libraries is discouraged, because those libraries contain the lessons that are being taught, and learning how to drive a car is quite different than learning how to build one.

Comment: @EdwinBuck FWIW, I gave your answer +1 for that reason.  I'm making minimal assumptions: all he said was that he wants certain behavior.  If he needs to implement it, the sources to both libraries might be helpful (although they're not simple libraries).  If he just needs history support, using one of these libraries will save a ton of work.

Comment: Thanks, and yes those libraries do save a ton of work, as does ncurses (which as Richard stated, can't be used).

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear if you want to handle your input better, or your terminal handling better.

If you want to handle input better, I suggest wrapping your character recogonition into a function that returns an integer, which has defines for each "handled" key.  That way your input looks more like

```
int char = readChar(input);
if (char == KEY_UP_ARROW) {
  ...
}
```

where readChar detects if the first key is an escape and then "peeks" to see if there is extra information available (to differentiate between a stand alone escape and the arrow keys).

If you intend to handle the screen side of things better, and your intent is to drive the terminal with your own wrapped terminal handling software, you need to reference the VT100 terminal reference (assuming that your xterm emulates VT100 (which many do)).  [The VT100 codes are described here](http://www.vt100.net/docs/vt100-ug/chapter3.html).

Note that the operating system does some extra processing on input (to combine key combinations, making programs easier to differentiate between deadkey keyboard setups, etc.), so you might to disable this in-terminal processing by putting the terminal in a different "mode".  Typical modes include "cooked", and "raw", where "raw" provides you with key codes that are not combined for simplicity.